# How to click on the play button of a youtube video embedded within smtebook through selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want click the youtube play in https://smtebooks.us/downfile/13192/building-serverless-python-web-services-zappa-pdf

my code is :

```
browser.switch_to.frame(0) 
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")
element.click()
```

but can not find element

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']"}
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Anyone have some idea how to deal with it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to handle embedded video player you need to switch to appropriate iframe and wait for button to appeared in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@src, "https://www.youtube.com/embed")]'))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@aria-label="Play"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Always switch to frame using name or some locator :

```
required_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.youtube.com')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(required_frame)
```

And then, below code works,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Play']")
element.click()
```

Answer (score -2):

If the only aim is to play the video, you can just refresh the page by using `driver.refresh()`

for e.g below works for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def watchvideo():
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/kamlesh/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXpzn8PAScw")
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(170)
driver.close()
```

Comment: If the chrome settings are configured to not play videos automatically then this workaround will not work obviously